# Centre a plot to the middle of a page using Knitr

Tags: r, pdf, rstudio, knitr

I'd like to align a plot to the center of a page of a knitr-generated pdf document. I can horizontally align the plot to the center using `fig.align='center'` but can't figure out how to get the plot vertically aligned to the center.

I've been using the following code:

````
---
header-includes: \usepackage{graphicx}
output: 
  pdf_document
geometry:
  left=1in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in
---


```{r,fig.align='center',out.extra='angle=90', echo=FALSE}

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(diamonds, aes(y=carat, x=price, colour=clarity))+geom_point()+
facet_wrap(~cut)

```
````

Answer (score 21, accepted):

On the LaTeX side, a vertically centered figure must be a [`figure` with position `p`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/28069/37118). How this can be achieved using `knitr` depends:

- If the figure has a caption, it is placed in a `figure` environment (see [`fig.env`](http://yihui.name/knitr/options/)). Then only the additional option `fig.pos = 'p'` is needed.
- If the figure has no caption (which is usually bad), you can manually add the `figure` environment:

  ````
  \begin{figure}[p]

  ```{r,fig.align='center',out.extra='angle=90', echo=FALSE}

  library(ggplot2)
  ggplot(diamonds, aes(y=carat, x=price, colour=clarity))+geom_point()+
  facet_wrap(~cut)

  ```
  \end{figure}
  ````

Note that this works when compiling to PDF but restricts you to PDF as output format.

Comment: I've spent several days (literally) trying to figure out how to knit a pdf with many images, but have only one image per page and vertically centered. I finally came across your solution for a single figure, but I'm having trouble adapting it for many images. Please help! :)

Comment: @nad7wf Have a look at [this gist](https://gist.github.com/ClaudiusL/2f2ae457f5953e1901e99c347ff4a6b5); I think it might solve your problem. If not, please open a new question (and ping me here so I get a notification). Hope that helps!