# Knit PDF from Rmarkdown with one image per page, vertically centered

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I have hundreds of images that I would like to knit to a single pdf file from Rmarkdown. I would like only one image per page, and for each image to be horizontally and vertically centered on the page. I've been playing around with the kable package for hours trying to accomplish, but no luck. Thanks for the help.

Here is an example set of images to work with:

```
filenames <- structure(list(img_url = c("https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/ce3/puppies-1-1308839.jpg", 
"https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/006/young-dachshund-1362378.jpg", 
"https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/20c/my-puppy-maggie-1362787.jpg"
)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Comment: I didn't realize that you've asked this question after posting [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33922757/centre-a-plot-to-the-middle-of-a-page-using-knitr#comment112046181_34132011). You didn't comment on my reply yet ...

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `glue` package to add in some LaTeX around each image and that should do what you want.

`glue` lets you put the variable right into the string, which you can then incorporate into the knitted file with the `results = 'asis' chunk option.

````
---
title: "One Image Per Page"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r one-per-page, results = 'asis', echo = FALSE}
library("glue")

# full path to all image files, URLs should work too
image_path_list <- c("/path/image1.jpg",
                     "/path/image2.jpg")

# create LaTeX output, alter the glue open delimiter to avoid conflict
glue('\\vspace*{\\fill}\n\\begin{center}\n\\includegraphics{{(image_path_list}}\n\\end{center}\n\\vspace*{\\fill}\n\\newpage\n', .open = "{(")

```
````

Comment: while elegant, this solution does not vertically center the images on the page, and that's the part I'm really struggling to figure out. Can you update this answer to include that fix? Thanks in advance.